# Drawing image to canvas from video (no error, but image is not drawn)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

I'm trying to draw an image to canvas from dynamically created video element. I have looked up several stack overflows and some solutions were 'add preload="auto" to video tag or switching the format of the video from mp4 to ogg. However neither of these work for me:

Here is my code in index.ejs:

```
<video id='current_vid' width="640" height="480" controls preload="auto"> 
</video>
<canvas id='canvas' width="200px" height="150px" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
```

Here is my code in my script.js:

```
let canvas,ctx;
window.onload = function(){
    $('#current_vid').attr('src','videos/sample.mp4'); //i have tried with ogg video as well
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let video_a = thumbnail(document.getElementById("current_vid"));    
}

function thumbnail(video) {
  ctx.drawImage(video, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

The dom shows the canvas element exists (as I can see the border and it's in my dev tools, but the image data from the video is not actually placed inside the canvas

Please comment what information you need, if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN, the `drawImage` function parameters are not the size of the image/canvas: 
see [void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

In short, dx and dy are not the size of the image, but the destination X and Y coordinates. You are drawing your image outside of the canvas. You should use `ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);`